# Div lado a lado fica ligeiramente mais baixa

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde, tenho estado a desenvolver uma pagina, muito semelhante a uma outra famosa, mas por algum motivo nas divs que tenho lado a lado uma delas fica mais baixa não sei porque, alguém sabe como corrigir isso?

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400&display=swap');
  *{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  body{
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
  h1{
   font-weight: 300;
   color: #404040;
   font-size: 64px;
  }
  div#content{
   margin: 30px auto;
   width: 50%;
  }
  .help{
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: monaco,courier,monospace;
   color: #404040;
  }
  .error{
   color: #999;
   font-size: 25px;
   font-weight: 400;
  }
  div#what{
   width: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  div#whnow{
   margin-left: 3%;
   width: 46%;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  div#boxs{
   margin-top: 10%;
  }
  div#boxs p{
   margin-top: 10px;
   line-height: 23px;
  }
  .emp{
   color: #2f7bbf;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .emp:hover{
   color: rgb(246,139,31);
   text-decoration: underline;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  div#rodape{
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 50px;
   border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  }
  div#rodape p{
   margin-top: 40px;
   font-family: monaco,courier,monospace;
   font-size: 12px;
  }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Direct IP Access Not Allowed | IMM Guard</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="content">
 <h1>Erro 1000 <label class="help">Request ID: dfgjk-sadfaf-asdfsdfa-asdf • Time: {time}</label></h1>
 <p class="error">Acesso Direto por IP não permitido!</p>
 <div id="boxs">
 <div id="what">
 <h2>O que está a acontecer?</h2>
 <p>Você está a tentar entrar num site protegido pela <a href="#" class="emp">IMM | GUARD</a> pelo IP dos nossos servidores, mas o nosso cliente pediu o bloqueio direto!</p>
 </div>
 <div id="whnow">
 <h2>O que posso fazer?</h2>
 <p>Para aceder a pagina que pretende, entre pelo endereço da pagina!</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="rodape">
 <p>IMM Request ID: 54adf0a09ada622e • Your IP: 2.81.244.98 • Proteja e acelere os seus sites com a <a href="#" class="emp">IMM | GUARD</a></p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara como vc colocou `display:inline-block` vc pode usar propriedades `inline` na `div`, e a propriedade que vai corrigir isso é a `vertical-align: top;` assim o conteúdo vai alinhar no `top` do `box-model`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código da imagem acima:**

***(exiba em Página toda para ver como fica já que a  parte responsiva parece que vc não fez ainda)***

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
h1{
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 64px;
}
div#content{
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.help{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: monaco,courier,monospace;
  color: #404040;
}
.error{
  color: #999;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
div#what{
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
div#whnow{
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 46%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
div#boxs{
  margin-top: 10%;
}
div#boxs p{
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 23px;
}
.emp{
  color: #2f7bbf;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.emp:hover{
  color: rgb(246,139,31);
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div#rodape{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
div#rodape p{
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-family: monaco,courier,monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Erro 1000 <label class="help">Request ID: dfgjk-sadfaf-asdfsdfa-asdf • Time: {time}</label></h1>
  <p class="error">Acesso Direto por IP não permitido!</p>
  <div id="boxs">
    <div id="what">
      <h2>O que está a acontecer?</h2>
      <p>Você está a tentar entrar num site protegido pela <a href="#" class="emp">IMM | GUARD</a> pelo IP dos nossos servidores, mas o nosso cliente pediu o bloqueio direto!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="whnow">
      <h2>O que posso fazer?</h2>
      <p>Para aceder a pagina que pretende, entre pelo endereço da pagina!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rodape">
    <p>IMM Request ID: 54adf0a09ada622e • Your IP: 2.81.244.98 • Proteja e acelere os seus sites com a <a href="#" class="emp">IMM | GUARD</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```